# Google Font simply not importing into my stylesheet

Tags: css, wordpress, fonts

I'm trying to import one into the stylesheet of my WordPress child theme. I used Google fonts on other sites and themes with no problems, but this one simply isn't working.

I import it with:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald);
```

And then in the class:

```
.nav-menu li a {
    color: #141412;
    display: block;
    font-size: 25px;
        font-family:'Oswald';
    line-height: 1;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

When I change the font-family to a generic font, the text does change. But no luck with several different Google fonts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The import and link is absolutely fine. It works, I've checked.
There is something else going on with your code. Could be the position of your import in your stylesheet, or some other override (maybe marked with !important). You could have defined the wrong class (.nav-menu li a), or you didn't linked the stylesheet to your theme and the list can continue.
A live site could help in this case. Otherwise, there's too much to take into consideration.

Comment: The class is correct and the stylesheet is linked; again, I can change the text to generic fonts like 'times' and 'san serif,' only the google fonts aren't working

Comment: Is it the first declaration in your css file? There has to be something wrong with your site or environment. Just told you I've checked the font, importing it in one of my themes. There's nothing special about Oswald. Is just your site.
Other than that, we can only assume a lot of stuff. Did you try @font-face?
Another supposition,try, for example, @import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald);